# UIImagePickerController doesn't work on iPhone11 Pro Max Simulator but all other cases are fine

Tags: swift, xcode

Swift: 5.1.3

Xcode: 11.3.1

Hi, I'm working with an app using UIImagePickerController and found out my code doesn't work when I run it on iPhone11 Pro Max Simulator.

How is iPhone11 Pro Max Simulator different from other simulators?

Here are methods related to UIIMagePickerController:

```
 @IBAction func uploadImageTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let pickerView = UIImagePickerController()

    // Set cameraroll sor chooseing a photo
    // choose '.camera' if you want to take the picture
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    self.present(pickerView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
.
.
.
extension RetailerProfileViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

// method that will be called when user choose the pic
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    // get the info of photo
    let image = info[.originalImage] as! UIImage
    // show it
    storeImage.image = image

    // dismiss the photo library
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: try not to add `UIImagePickerConrollerDelegate` delegate in `extension`...

Comment: It didn't fix the problem

Comment: try removing extension and add `UIImagePickerConrollerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in the same `UIVIewController` class...